# Webcontainer / EJB-container : JSF Managed Beans?

Tags: ejb, containers, managed-bean, presentation, web-container

In which container are the JSF Managed Beans supposed to be in? In the webcontainer or in the EJB-container?

As I understand it, the presentationslayer - which should be the webcontainer - should contain the JSF Managed Beans?
The EJB-container should only contain the EJB-beans, which have the business logic and webservices? Am I right here?

I have been googling for an answer without finding anything, so hopefully I can get some help here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSF does not run in the EJB-container. Tomcat only has a web container but supports JSF and managed beans.

Servlets run in the web container. Since JSF uses a servlet (FacesServlet) it will run in the web container.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnacj.html) you can se what is available in the Web and EJB containers.